# Node reference is lost after modifying a class name

Tags: javascript

I lost object reference after changing the class name through node.className = ...

```
var nodeName = 'my_div';
var subNode = document.getElementById(nodeName);
var nodes = subNode.getElementsByClassName('one');
alert (nodes[0]); // OK - [object HTMLSpanElement]
nodes[0].setAttribute('class','zzz');
alert (nodes[0]); // Undefined
```

How do I save a reference to the object in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live collection, that means any changes to the original dom elements attributes will be reflected in the list.

You can use a method like [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) which returns a non live set of elements

```
var nodes = subNode.querySelectorAll('.one');
```

Comment: QSA is a good suggestion. Separately: If you need to convert a live NodeList to an array: `var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList, 0);`

Comment: QSA is also a good suggestion because it's present on IE8, whereas `getElementsByClassName` is not. (And that's my lonely +1 there, btw.) But one thing worth noting: Although it's rare that it will matter, `getElementsByClassName` (and its better-supported cousin `getElementsByTagName`) are **dramatically** faster than QSA, even allowing for converting their results into arrays: http://jsperf.com/qsa-vs-gebcn-vs-gebtn-to-array This is likely to be for two reasons: 1. The browser probably already has the class/tag list for CSS reasons, and 2. QSA has to fire up a full CSS selector parser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the benchmark... I had never tested the performance difference